# How to enable "login as page" for facebook authentication?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to enable "login as page" for my site, but this is what facebook says (`S3auth` is the name of my page):

[image]

How to fix this and where to read about this type of login?

Comment: You mean login to an app? AFAIK only users can do that, not pages.

Comment: Yes, login to an app.. Can you give a link to this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Login as page" is not possible, but you could use graph API to fetch user's page data using `manage_pages` permission and allow them to perform tasks on your site.

Quoted from [facebook permissions doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/):

> Enables your application to retrieve access_tokens for Pages and Applications that the user administrates. The access tokens can be queried by calling //accounts via the Graph API. This permission is only compatible with the Graph API, not the deprecated REST API. 
>   See here for generating long-lived Page access tokens that do not expire after 60 days.